# Use Mercurial API to Get Changes to a Repository For a Given Changeset

Tags: python, mercurial, dvcs, changeset, mercurial-extension

How can I use the Mercurial API to determine the changes made to a repository for each changeset? I am able to get a list of files relevant to a particular revision, but I cannot figure out how to tell what happened to that file.

How can I answer these questions about each file in a changeset:

- Was it added?
- Was it deleted?
- Was it modified?

Is there an attribute in the file context that will tell me this (if so, I cannot find it), or there ways to figure this out by other means?

Here is my code:

```
def index(request):
    u = ui.ui()
    repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), '/path/to/repo')
    changes = repo.changelog
    changesets = []

    for change in changes:
        ctx = repo.changectx(change)
        fileCtxs = []
        for aFile in ctx.files():
            if aFile in ctx:
                for status in repo.status(None, ctx.node()):
                    # I'm hoping this could return A, M, D, ? etc
                    fileCtxs.append(status)

        changeset = {
            'files':ctx.files(),
            'rev':str(ctx.rev()),
            'desc':ctx.description(),
            'user':ctx.user(),
            'filectxs':fileCtxs,
        }
        changesets.append(changeset)

    c = Context({
        'changesets': changesets,
    })

    tmplt = loader.get_template('web/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(tmplt.render(c))
```

Comment: I'm curious, what are you building with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`localrepo.status()` can take contexts as argument (`node1` and `node2`).

See http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/6505773080e4/mercurial/localrepo.py#l973

Comment: I gave this a try and all I get back are lists of files that I can't seem to make sense of. They aren't the files that changed and there is no modified, added, removed, deleted, unknown, ignored, or clean information.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. Each set of lists returned corresponds to a different status. Thanks!

Comment: The value returnes are: `modified, added, removed, deleted, unknown, ignored, clean`

Comment: Some of them will only be filled if you pass `clean=True` or `ignored=True` for performance reasons.

Comment: The link is not up to date any longer.